# SQL Filter - To protect aganist injection

Tags: javascript, python, http, server, proxy

I want to create a filter to protect against SQL injection attacks. as the below image
[image]

I want to know how we can interpret the HTTP request in the middle of the client and server and after capturing the request if any request finds malicious I want to block the request.

Comment: Just use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: i dont want to change anything  in code

Comment: It looks like you're looking for an Intrusion Detection/Protection System, which is a component of a firewall. These scan the web requests for common injection attacks.

Comment: yes something like ips or ids

Comment: So use a firewall with an IDS. Don't try to program this yourself, it takes lots of research.